# Editing row in PrimeReact DataTable when data is nested and avoiding flattening

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, primereact

I have defined a primereact datatable which takes nested data which is managed from a state:

The data:

```
{
  id: <some_id>,
  text: {
    en: <english_text>,
    de: <german_text>
  }
}
```

The Editor Function:

```
const TableEditor = () => {

  const data = useSelector(dataState);
  const activeLanguage = useSelector(activeLangState)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function _onChange(e) {
   dispatch(setData(e.newData));
  }
  
  const textEditor = (options) => {
     return <InputTextarea value={options.value} onChange={(e) => options.editorCallback(e.target.value)}/>

  }

  return (
            <DataTable value={data} editMode="row" 
                onRowEditComplete={(e) => _onChange(e)}
                dataKey="id">
                <Column field={`text.${activeLanguage}`} header={"Text"} editor={(options) => textEditor(options)} />
                <Column rowEditor headerStyle={{ width: '10%', minWidth: '8rem' }} bodyStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}></Column>
            </DataTable>
        )
}
```

The problem with the following is that PrimeReact will flatten my data object on edit and create something like:

```
{
  id: <some_id>,
  text: {
    en: <english_text>,
    de: <german_text>
  },
  text.en: <english_text>
}
```

Thus when a rowEdit is done only `text.en` will be changed and the actual data inside the nested `text` property will remain unchanged. I tried using the `body` property of the Column element and not include `field` at all, but then I cannot access the value that needs to be changed through `options` inside the `textEdtior`.

```
const TableEditor = () => {

  const data = useSelector(dataState);
  const activeLanguage = useSelector(activeLangState)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function _onChange(e) {
   dispatch(setData(e.newData));
  }
  
  const textEditor = (options) => {
     // here options.value will now be empty so one idea would be to directly access rowData
     // but that would make the field uneditable as it is now connected to the state which isn't
     // changed here
     return <InputTextarea value={options.rowData.text[activeLanguage]} onChange={(e) => options.editorCallback(e.target.value)}/>

  }

  const textTemplate = (node) => {
    return <div>{node.text[activeLanguage]}</div>
  }

  return (
            <DataTable value={data} editMode="row" 
                onRowEditComplete={(e) => _onChange(e)}
                dataKey="id">
                <Column header={"Text"} body={textTemplate} editor={(options) => textEditor(options)} />
                <Column rowEditor headerStyle={{ width: '10%', minWidth: '8rem' }} bodyStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}></Column>
            </DataTable>
        )
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the array flattening and change the nested object instead?